Tiles getting generated in both PostgreSQL and gwc directory?
I have a GeoServer 2.21.0 installed on EC2 instance with Ubuntu server.
Initially I tried creating tiles in with default blob storage on file system which is the geoserver/data_dir/gwc directory. Soon we ran out of Inodes, looking for solutions I found out I can store the tiles in PostgresSQL.
PGSQL 15 was already hosted on the EC2 instance, I configured the disk quota with external database and updated the connection information.
Disk quota configured successfully, I created new tile layer, configured it with my local JS app to test. The tile loads successfully in JS app, however they take a bit longer compared to file blob storage.
I went into my pgsql database and checked table
tile_cache=# SELECT * FROM tileset;
                       key                       |         layer_name          | gridset_id | blob_format | parameters_id | bytes  
-------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------+-------------+---------------+--------
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |data:datanamelayer | EPSG:4326  | image/png   |               | 507904
 ___GLOBAL_QUOTA___                              |                             |            |             |               | 507904
(2 rows)

tile_cache=# SELECT * FROM tilepage;

                          key                          |                   tileset_id                    | page_z | page_x | page_y | creation_time_minutes | frequency_of_use | last_access_time_minutes | fill_factor | num_hits 
-------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+-----------------------+------------------+--------------------------+-------------+----------
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@0,0,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      0 |      0 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@0,1,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      0 |      1 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@1,0,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      1 |      0 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@1,1,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      1 |      1 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@2,0,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      2 |      0 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@2,1,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      2 |      1 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@3,0,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      3 |      0 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@3,1,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      3 |      1 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@4,0,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      4 |      0 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png@4,1,4 |data:datanamelayer#EPSG:4326#image/png |      4 |      4 |      1 |              28688109 |                0 |                 28688109 |           1 |        0
(10 rows)

Everything great till here. However GWC keeps on creating files in gwc directory as well
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jul 18 08:27 EPSG_4326_04
ubuntu@ip-0-0-0-0:/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/datanamelayer$ cd EPSG_4326_04/
ubuntu@ip-0-0-0-0:/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/datanamelayer/EPSG_4326_04$ ls -l
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 18 08:27 3_0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 18 08:27 3_1
ubuntu@ip-0-0-0-0:/usr/share/geoserver/data_dir/gwc/datanamelayer/EPSG_4326_04$ 

I deleted all the files "datanamelayer" folder form gwc directory. Refreshed the JS application calling the tile service via WMTS. Hoping this time it would take png files from PostgreSQL database however it did not. "datanamelayer" was again created in gwc directory.
Is this a known issue?

The disk quota database does not store tiles, it just stores a ledger of how much space the tiles use on disk, and how frequently/recently they have been accessed. When the quota is reached, this information is used to decide which tiles to delete, to go back below quota. That's all.

I see, postgressql can not be used to store tile data? using S3 blob store is the only way?

It cannot right now, but one can write a new BlobStore (as Java code) that can then write tiles in PostgreSQL database. The default storage is file system, S3, Azure blob store, Swift, and SQLite are other possible options. Some of them have zip packages available as GeoServer extensions, other as community modules, and others have to be built from sources.

Alright this helps a lot thank you @Andrea for you time
